# Parameters or arguments in bash

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu

I saw a question on stackflow about parsing arguments. I tried to write this, but it's not working and now it's getting on my nerves.

The usual way of running a script on the terminal is `./scriptname`, but I later introduced the argument `-d`. So, if I put `./scriptname` it will not run. If I put `./scriptname -d` it will.

Now I want to put another argument for the path (where the files are moving, in this case `"/home/elg19/documents"`) such that when I do not include the path, it won't run. But, if I put `./scriptname -d path` I want to replace `$To` in the existing script with the command argument after `-d`.

```
#!/bin/bash
From="/home/mark/doc"
To=$2

if [ $1 = -d ]; then
    cd "$From"
    for i in pdf txt doc; do
      find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$To" \;
    done
fi
```

Comment: And what seems to be the problem? Apart from improvements like: check if $2 is directory, changing `if [ $1 = -d ]` to `if [ "x$1" = "x-d" ]` & possibility of avoiding `cd` by using `find "$From" -type f ...` instead of `find . -type f ...` script seems to be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired usage isn't completely clear, but it seems to be:

```
scriptname -d path
```

So, you can do it the extensible way, or the brute force way.  Since you're changing directories willy-nilly, you also need to ensure that the paths are absolute, not relative.

#### Brute force

```
#!/bin/bash
From="/home/mark/doc"
if [ $# = 2 ] && [ "$1" = '-d' ] && [ -d $2 ]
then
    case "$2" in
    (/*) cd "$From" &&
         for extn in pdf txt doc
         do find . -type f -name "*.$extn" -exec mv {} "$To" \;
         done;;
    (*)  echo "$0: path name must be absolute ($2 is not)" 1>&2; exit 1;;
    esac
else
    echo "Usage: $0 -d /absolute/dirname" 1>&2; exit 1
fi
```

#### Extensible

```
#!/bin/bash
From="/home/mark/doc"
To=""

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0 .sh) -d /absolute/dirname" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

while getopts d: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    (d)  if [ ! -d "$OPTARG" ]
         then echo "$0: $OPTARG is not a directory" 1>&2; exit 1
         else
             case "$OPTARG" in
             (/*) To="$OPTARG";;
             (*)  echo "$0: path name must be absolute ($2 is not)" 1>&2; exit 1;;
             esac
         fi;;
    (*)  usage;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

if [ $# != 0 ] || [ -z "$To" ]
then usage
fi

cd "$From" &&
for extn in pdf txt doc
do find . -type f -name "*.$extn" -exec mv {} "$To" \;
done
```

For example, it will be very easy to add a `-f from` option to deal with changing the source of the files.

Note that you could also use:

```
for extn in pdf txt doc
do find "$From" -type f -name "*.$extn" -exec mv {} "$To" \;
done
```

This would allow you to permit relative names for the 'from' and 'to' directories because it does not change directory.

Comment: I suppose that you could allow relative pathnames for the 'to' directory, but documenting that they would be interpreted relative to the 'from' directory (currently a fixed location) is not immediately obvious behaviour.  You normally specify pathnames to a command relative to the current directory (think of any of the regular basic Unix commands - they all work with names relative to the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do some input validation to your command line arguments. I guess the following would be somewhat useful:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "USAGE :"
    echo "./move -d <to-directory>"
}

if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
    usage
    exit
fi

case $1 in
    -d ) shift
         To=$1
         ;;
    *  ) usage
         exit
esac

From="/tmp/From/"

cd "$From"
for i in pdf txt doc; do
    find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$To" \;
done
```

Moreover to debug your script, you may use the following command:

```
bash -x ./move.sh -d /tmp/To/
```

You may add more error checking (and informative echo's) for the following cases:

- Source/destination directory does not exits
- N files have been copied from the  to
- No files available at
- You can take the type of files as arguments f.e. -t doc xls pdf

Comment: Report the command name via `$0` (not `./move`, because it probably won't be in the current directory once it is a working command).  Also, conventionally, the usage message is on one line, reported to standard error, and the exit status is not zero.  Even though the double semi-colon before `esac` is optional, leaving it out is bad form.  On the whole, it is best to check that the directory name argument does represent a directory; and given the `cd` (which should itself be checked), the 'to' name needs to be absolute.